Diferencia entre "pagar a escote" y "pagar a pachas"
La dos expresiones parecen querer decir que cada uno paga una parte del gasto total hecho, pero ¿quieren decir lo mismo o hay diferencias entre ellas? Aquí se indica:

... Lo que no está tan claro es cómo hacer ese reparto o división que implica a escote. “Pagando cada uno la parte que le corresponde en un gasto común”, que es como lo define el DLE, queda abierta la puerta a interpretaciones diversas sobre cómo decidir esa “parte”.
**Hay quienes apuestan por que cada uno pague en función de lo que haya consumido o elegido –a más caro, más pago–; para otros, es pagar a medias o a pachas, ... dividir el gasto a partes iguales, sea lo que sea lo pedido por cada uno. ¿En qué quedamos?

¿Corresponde una a que "cada uno paga su parte" y la otra a "se divide el gasto por igual entre todos"? En ese caso, ¿cuál es cual?
Y ¿hay una expresión para cuando se reparte el gasto (por ejemplo, de una comida con muchos comensales) entre todos por igual, salvo una persona a la que el grupo invita?

Mmm la información en la web sobra, hay algo en particular que te confunda? Sinceramente, yo busco en todas las páginas y no me parece que hay ninguna discrepancia ni ambigüedad al definirse la diferencia entre ambos conceptos.

Bien ahí, ahora sí queda claro cuál es la pregunta. Mirando las definiciones del DLE, al hablar en 'escote'  de correspondencia a mí me suena a que se refiere a proporcionalidad. Aunque es cierto que puede darse esa ambigüedad que menciona la página.

Tras consultar varios foros en los que se mantiene este debate, parece que el uso es diferente no solo para cada región, sino para cada individuo.
El debate más interesante lo he encontrado en https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/pagar-a-escote.2982195/:
Como ni siquiera la RAE da una respuesta clara, uno de los debatientes hizo la pregunta al departamento de "Español al día".
El resumen de la respuesta dice lo siguiente:
“Si bien es cierto que puede existir cierta ambigüedad en la expresión a escote, también es seguro que entre la considerable documentación que se puede encontrar de tal uso, ninguna existe en la que claramente se pueda deducir que alberga el significado de 'pagando cada uno la parte exacta de su consumo o gasto', todo lo más, insistimos, se encuentran textos ambiguos que solo dejarían el sentido exacto a la intuición de cada hablante.”
En el mismo foro, un participante también mencionó lo siguiente:
“Es un dialogo de la serie "Cuéntame como pasó" (temporada 7, capitulo 110) que tiene lugar en un restaurante bastante caro (explicaciones entre paréntesis son mías*):

Yo pido una tortilla francesa. (el plato más barato de la carta)
No, mujer. Van a pagar estos señores. (puedes ponerte las botas)
Seguro que pagan a escote. (pues no, cada uno tendrá que pagar su parte propia)
Que no, mujer.
Antoñito.
Sí.
Esto lo pagamos tú y yo a pachas. (pagamos tú y yo a partes iguales)
¿Cómo tú y yo?…”

*del autor
Algunas expresiones relacionadas en el uso diario:
A escote: Alguien paga el importe íntegro y luego lo cobra de sus compañeros.
A pachas: Una vez lo mismo como a escote, otra vez como a medias. ("A pachas" es menos conocida, totalmente desconocida en muchos lugares)
A medias: (Entre dos personas) Cada uno paga la misma cantidad de dinero.
Hacer el bote: Todos los miembros del grupo aportan una cantidad de dinero al inicio y se guarda en un fondo común. En Hispanoamérica y en Andalucía se usan por esto la expresión “hacer una vaquita”.
A rondas: Todos se turnan para pagar.
Cuentas separadas: Cada uno paga por su consumo.

This is a link-only answer.
While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

"Hacer una vaquita" parece que es una expresión argentina. Aquí en Andalucía no se usa. ¿Las explicaciones entre paréntesis son tuyas o del usuario de otro foro? Tu respuesta parece un pastiche de trozos recortados al azar de otros sitios y que además no acaba de responder a la pregunta original

@RubioRic: Siempre tengo mis respuestas verificadas con amigos y conocidos. El uso común de «hacer la vaquita» me lo confirman desde Sevilla (“eso es hacer una vaquita aquí”) y desde Jerez de la Frontera, Cádiz (“es muy común hacer una vaquita”).

Coincido contigo en que la definición de la RAE es ambigua. Pero al ser consultada directamente en el enlace adjuntado por user37164 responde esto

Sin embargo, no hay duda alguna de su empleo sumamente cuantioso con
el significado concreto de 'pagando cada uno la misma cantidad', que
es lo que el común de los hablantes entiende.

Es decir, para el representante de la RAE, para muchos participantes de ese foro y para mí:

pagar a escote = pagar a pachas = pagar a partes iguales

Por otro lado, no conozco ninguna expresión de ese estilo para cuando todo un grupo invita a una persona. Existe un sinónimo para invitar que es convidar, pero puede usarse cuando una sola persona invita a otra.
